# Regex replacing a string while saving parts of it

Tags: python, regex, django

I was wondering if it's possible to reserve some of an excisting value, while replacing. Example:

**Original:**

```
{u'America': u'A'}
```

**After replacing:**

```
{u'America': _(u'A')}
```

`u\'[w]\'` selects the value properly, however how do I save `'A'` to the replacement value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capture group:

```
In [13]: s = "{u'America': u'A'}"

In [14]: re.sub(r"(u'[\w]')", r"_(\1)", s)
Out[14]: "{u'America': _(u'A')}"
```

Here, `(...)` captures what's inside the parentheses, and `\1` inserts it into the replacement string.